# how to display data that have store in sharedpreferences in calendar by date (android)

Tags: android, calendar

sorry for my broken english.
i want to ask anyone about retrieving data that have been store in sharedpreferences.
my situation now, i have lists of checkbox. then, the list of checked checkbox will be display in another activity.
after that, i create calendar by calendarview. the problem is, i want to display the list of checked checkbox based on the date of people checked. for an example,today 12/10/2015, i was checked the checkbox. when i go to calendarview activity, i click the date of 12/10/2015 and the checked checkbox will display.
i dont know how to explain more longer about it because im still learning android.
i hope have somebody there will help me to solve this problems.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store date along with your date in shared preferences when the check box is being checked. Then you can display in the calendar view based on the date which is stored.

Comment: aha.. can you passed me the code?? usually i using sharedpreferences to store text.. so how to store with date in sharedpreferences?

Comment: Convert date into string and then store it in shared preferences.